# Converting word documents into a Trac wiki format

Tags: windows, conversion, microsoft-word, wiki, trac

I'm working on a development team that uses [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) to maintain a software product that we are developing, and after working with our technical writer, we decided that we should try to put our test procedure documents into our wiki.

Unfortunately, these are all Word docs.  Mostly Word 2003.  We just converted to Word 2k7, so I have its conversion abilities available.

**Does anyone know of a way that I can convert my word documents into wiki-formatted text?**  I tried looking at [Word2Wiki](http://sourceforge.net/projects/word2wiki/) but the app says it doesn't work with Word2k7.

I'm also okay with converting our word documents to another, intermediary format, before converting it to wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forget all those tools.

Microsoft Word allows you to export in HTML. Export HTML, copy-paste, remove 'html' 'head' and 'body' tags, and surround with [HTML WikiProcessor](http://bitten.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiHtml).

If the styles don't come through well, try exporting to RTF and using an RTF to HTML converter. Then proceed.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that you can use this HTML WikiProcessor with Trac.  Very cool.  However, I am running into issues with style tag that are throwing errors in Trac.

Comment: I tried using the latter option you mentioned, and its much better.  Used DocFrac to convert the RTF to HTML.  There were a number of characters that didn't translate that well and had to be search&replaced, but that can be automated with sed.  Very useful!

Answer (score 7):

[OpenOffice.org](http://openoffice.org) has builtin functionality to export in wiki format. You can also easily convert between Word documents and OOo's `.odt` format prior to exporting.

File -> Export (set format to MediaWiki)

Wikipedia also has a list of [Wiki Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Tools/Editing_tools), coincidentally. Section 6 is what you're interested in.

---

**Edit:**

Since I was unaware that Trac uses a different format, Trac also provides [some tools](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWikiConversion) to convert from MediaWiki syntax to Trac syntax. You can use these after using any of the aforementioned tools.

Comment: +1 for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_tools#Importing_.28converting.29_content_to_Wikipedia_.28MediaWiki.29_format

Answer (score 3):

Be sure and check these out:

- [TracWysiwigPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracWysiwygPlugin)
- [Word2Trac VB Script](http://gillius.org/Word2Trac.bas)

Answer (score 0):

From Google Groups [originally by Jason:](http://groups.google.com/group/trac-users/browse_thread/thread/bb60e3a59a363754/40d11fe10d188c44?#40d11fe10d188c44)

> I've used [the attached macro](http://groups.google.com/group/trac-users/attach/90bcbc665cd69493/Word2Trac.zip?part=2)
>   (hopefully it doesn't get marked as an
>   unsafe attachment) with success. It is
>   based on a modified version of a macro
>   found [here](http://tikiwiki.org/tiki-index.php?page=WordToWiki)
>
> **Instructions:**
>
> - Open Word.
> - Open the Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11).
> - Select File → Import File... (Ctrl+M) and select Word2Trac.bas.
> - Open a document in Word.
> - Run the macro: Tools → Macros → Macros (Alt-F8), select the macro, and
>     press Run.
> - The conversion will modify the document in-place (don't save it!) and
>     automatically copy the results to the
>     clipboard.
> - Paste the markup into Trac and clean up the markup in whatever way
>     necessary.
>
> I've also used the TracWysiwygPlugin
>   to copy/paste the document. It works
>   decently with most formatting,
>   although it generates horrible and
>   often broken wiki where it adds extra
>   BRs for no reason, adds loads of extra
>   spaces (which doesn't affect output
>   but affects source), and sometimes
>   deletes the spaces between words
>   making a huge runon word.
>
> I usually use the wysiwyg plugin to
>   paste and then correct the output by
>   hand, but I use the macro too
>   sometimes, which works usually
>   perfectly for the content that it
>   supports.

Comment: Oops I only just now notice the Word2Trac script is in Arathorn's answer :-(